# How to use the value of a variable when an event handler is set, instead of the value when it's executed

Tags: javascript

I have 10 divs, with id's key0, key1, key2, etc. In my initialize function I was trying to run a loop to add event handlers to all of them, like so:

```
for (x=0; x<=9; x++){
    document.getElementById("key" + x).addEventListener("click", function(){ numClick(x) }, false);
}
```

The goal being to set up each div with an event that would send the corresponding number to the numClick function when it was clicked. I mistakenly expected it to set the value of the variable when the event handler was assigned, but of course it doesn't. So every time one of the divs is clicked it always sends a value of 10, since that is what x ends up at after the loop.

I've been trying to figure out a way to make this work but so far I haven't come up with anything.

Comment: so your problem is in ("key" + x) . right?

Comment: @Soombinakundi: No, that is executed in the loop itself. The problem is `numClick(x)` as that is executed by the event handler some time after the loop has ended.

Comment: no the ("key" + x) works fine. it's the numClick(x) that's the problem. because at the time the divs are clicked, the loop has run in it's entirety and x = 10.

Comment: I just want to suggest you a different approach. Not sure if you like it, though: http://jsfiddle.net/LgyxY/

Comment: @TimoVirkkunen I'll be honest, I don't really understand what's going on in your fiddle, I'm still very much learning. But it looks interesting so I'm going to spend some time figuring it out.

Comment: It's ok :) I try to explain it: first the code finds all HTML elements which belong to class `key`. That's the `class="key"` in the HTML. Then it will loop through all these elements and adds the `eventListener` to them and gets the function argument value from the element's attribute declared in HTML with `data-key=[VALUE]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Timo. I've pretty much been able to figure out what all the code does. The only line that's giving me trouble is this: var keys = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("key"));  I understand what the end result is, keys ends up being an array that contains every element with class="key", but I don't understand HOW it's doing it. I haven't worked with arrays that much, I don't know any of those array methods, so I'm going to have to look at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an immediately executed function expression inside the loop, that will create a scope for each iteration where you can have a variable instance:

```
for (x=0; x<=9; x++){
  (function(y){
    document.getElementById("key" + y).addEventListener("click", function(){ numClick(y) }, false);
  })(x);
}
```

Comment: When does y get a value?

Comment: Nevermind i see it now

Comment: @SometimesDirty: The function is called with `(x)`, which gives the value for the parameter `y`.

Comment: Ok this is working great, thanks! I haven't quite wrapped my head around why yet though.